# Showing loading animation when bootstrap modal loading contents

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap modal to show larger version of images in my website. When someone clicks on the image, I open the modal and load the image using jQuery's `html()` function.

```
jQuery('.myimage').click (function () {

            // determine the URL of the image to show
            var imageURLLarge = "some/cdn/location";

            // load the image in a DIV element inside modal
            jQuery('#imgContent').html ('<img src="' + imageURLLarge + '"');

            // show the modal
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

The code works fine and shows the image. But if the image is large, though the modal appears, it takes some time for the image to show-up. I want to show a progress-bar or loading animation during that waiting time. How do I do that?

I looked up a few places and they mostly suggested using JQuery's AJAX methods like `load()`. But I could not use AJAX as my images are coming from different URLs (CDN) and same URL security policy of AJAX is preventing me.

Any help / direction will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the modal as shown in the [doc's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), and simply put the data attributes the image wrapper.  This way you get all the built in functionality of it pre-loading, etc.

```
<a class="myimg" 
    href="yourlargeimage.jpg" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#myModal"
><img src="yoursmallimage.jpg" /></a>
```

If a `remote` URL is provided (your larger image), content will be loaded **one time** via jQuery's load method and injected into the `.modal-content` div. If you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the `href` attribute to specify the remote source.

Comment: That's because I don't want to load the large images in the very beginning. I am normally showing smaller sized images in the web-page so that the page can load faster. Only if somebody clicks on the image, then I want to show the larger version...

Comment: The images or url in the `href` attribute only loads in the modal when you click on it, not from the *beginning*. So if you have your smaller images inside of the `<a>` tag from the beginning, then this should all work nicely.